# Laravel 5 - How to use union in more than two tables/queries with Query Builder or Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, unions

I have 10 tables that i want 'union'. Here my table name with same fields.

```
sell_2007
sell_2008
sell_2009
...
sell_2015
sell_2016
```

In the example given by laravel do union in the two tables only (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#unions), how if the table more than two tables/queries? In my case there are 10 tables. How to do that with Query Builder or Eloquent?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add multiple unions like this;

```
$first = DB::table('sell_2007');
$second = DB::table('sell_2008');

$users = DB::table('users')
        ->union($first)
        ->union($second)
        ->get();
```

You may find that you get better perfomance to union the tables using RAW SQL query.

Comment: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns..

Comment: You will need specify the same number of columns for each table in the union